# Chilli plant showing deformed leaves with brown traces under leaves

Tags: chili, pest-damage

I am having trouble finding what is causing my chilli plant to look unhealthy. My googling suggest it *may* be a pest problem but there are no signs of pests on the plant. I have briefly seen the odd bug that is long and narrow that jumps/flys away as I get close.

Symptoms are browning around edges of leaves, dark brown traces on underside of leaves and leaf curling/cupping.
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFgm4.jpg)
[image]

[image]

Comment: I have seen leaves like in image #2 and #3 on my asparagus bean and Mandevilla plant. I would be interested in knowing what is the cause.